# React Native Flatlist - onMomentumScrollEnd

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am facing the issue in onMomentumScrollEnd function, It is working multiple times.
please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
        <FlatList
            style = { ...}
            data = {data}
            initialNumToRender={10}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
            onMomentumScrollBegin={() => {
                this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = false;
            }}
            onEndReached={() => {
                if (!this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum) {
                    this.retrieveMore(); // LOAD MORE DATA
                    this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = true;
                }
            }}
        />
```